# Session management in flutter inappwebview

Tags: flutter, session, flutter-inappwebview

I am currently working on a Flutter app that utilizes a headless web view with the flutter-inappwebview package. My goal is to enable seamless navigation between multiple user accounts within the web view without requiring manual login each time. To achieve this, I follow the following approach:

1. After logging in to a specific website using the web view, I retrieve the cookies, which contain the session information.
2. I store these cookies in the app's cache directory for later use.
3. When I need to switch accounts, I attempt to inject the stored cookies into the web view to restore the session.

While this approach works perfectly well using Python Selenium, allowing me to effortlessly switch between multiple accounts using their respective sessions, I encounter an issue when attempting the same approach with flutter-inappwebview. Despite successfully injecting the cookies into the web view, it has no effect on the login status.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.